# Cambiar cabeceras con sus corresponsales en otro archivo

Tags: python, pandas

Sé que hay una entrada para esta cuestión, pero haciendo lo que se dice me salta un error y no entiendo el motivo.

Tengo un archivo que tiene 260 columnas con sus cabeceras (df1). Luego tengo otro archivo que tiene esos nombres de cabeceras con sus "traducciones" (df2). Necesito cambiar los nombres de las cabeceras del df2 por las traducciones del df2.

Os muestro las cabeceras de algunas de las columnas: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta imagen de abajo corresponde al documento que tengo. Veréis que en la columna izquierda aparecen los nombres de columna original (los del DF1; es decir, los de la foto de arriba) y, en la columna derecha, están los nuevos nombres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi objetivo es que en el DF1, las columnas pasen a tener los nombres de la columna "Nombre Columna Nuevo". No sé si me explico.

Las columnas no están en el mismo orden. Por así decirlo, necesitaría un "buscarv" para reemplazar los nombres de cabeceras del DF1 por sus traducciones del DF2.

Este es el proceso que he seguido:

```
df=pd.read_csv("ruta/archivo.csv", keep_default_na=False, na_values=[""])
```

Luego sigo las indicaciones que he visto en la respuesta que dieron a otro usuario con el mismo problema:

```
df2=pd.read_excel("ruta.xlsx").set_index(0)

traduccion=df2[1].to_dict()

df=df.rename(traduccion, axis=1)
```

Problema?

Me salta este error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Y, entiendo, el error está aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado por internet, pero no saco nada en claro. ¿Qué hago mal?

Muchas gracias,

Un saludo,

Comment: Okay perdona las molestias!, borro la respuesta, a ver si soy capaz de datarte una solución acertada :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una solución que yo creo es más simple. Nuestro dataframe 1 tiene lo siguiente:

```
      B       C       A       D        E       F       G      H
0   sergio  raul    maria   jose    arturo  adolfo  juana   pedro
```

Nuestro damaframe 2 (el que tiene los nuevos nombres:

```
    old new
0   A   a
1   B   b
2   C   c
3   D   d
4   E   e
5   F   f
6   G   g
7   H   h
```

Ahora guardamos los nombres de las columnas sin traducir del segundo dataframe (la parte de `astype('str')` es por si acaso hay caracteres que entorpezcan el tipado, o por si las columnas fuesen números). Finalmente se actualiza el nombre de las columnas del primer dataframe.

```
columnas_viejas = df2['Nombre columna original'].astype('str')
df1= df1[columnas_viejas]
df1.columns = df2['Nombre columna nuevo']
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
      a        b     c        d        e      f       g       h
0   maria   sergio  raul    jose    arturo  adolfo  juana   pedro
```

Espero que te haya servido, un saludo.

Comment: Hola Sergio! Y gracias por tu comentario. No entiendo eso de "df_antiguo[columnas_viejas]. ¿Qué dataframe representa que es?

Comment: Perdona, debí utilizar los mismos nombres que usaste tu. He editado la respuesta para ver si así esta más claro.
En cualquier caso `df_antiguo[columnas_viejas]` lo que hace es un slicing, que basicamente es de un dataframe, coger unicamente ciertas columnas.

Comment: ¡Genial! Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo renombrando las columnas ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import os
import re

filename='libro1.xlsx'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(str(filename), logfile=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
df = pd.read_excel(wb,engine='xlrd')

# nombres originales
print(df.columns)

# limpiamos los nombres de columnas eliminando los caracter especiales
# y asignando el resultado a la variable resultado
# _events_ son 8 caracteres que removemos al principio y _ que es 1 al final 
resulto = [re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '_', df.columns[k])[8:-1] for k,v in enumerate(df.columns) ]

# renombramos las columnas
df.columns = resulto

#imprimimos
print(df.columns)
```

## nombres originales

```
Index(['{events}{profile}{last_update}', '{event}{profile}{time_update}'], dtype='object')
```

## resultado:

```
Index(['profile_last_update', 'profile_time_update'], dtype='object')
```

## si los nombres siempre son los mismos puedes crear un arreglo y asignarlo a `df.columns` directamente:

```
columnas = ['profile_last_update', 'profile_time_update']
df.columns = columnas
```

Comment: Me da un error constantemente: "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame". Me da el error en esta línea: 

2 wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename, logfile=open(os.devnull, 'w'))

En cualquier caso, tu proceso, según me parece entender, lo que hace es "editar" los nombres de las columnas del DF1, ¿no? Lo digo porque puede parecer que las traducciones son iguales pero sin algunos símbolos o caracteres, y no es así: hay casos en los que la traducción no tiene nada que ver...

Comment: sorry solo debes inclui `str(filename)`.... en cuanto a lo otro si asi mismo puedes crear un dict `columnas={ "{events}{profile}{last_update}" : 'profile_last_update'}` y agregar un `resultado.append(columnas[df.columns[k]])` y eso solo te devolveria el valor que seria la traduccion